# removing sql logins from one server, after migrating to another server, but all the databases were not migra

Tags: sql-server, security, logins

Here are the details of the production environment:

I have `2 serevrs`, `A1` and `A2`.

I have completely transfered 100 logins from server `A1` to `A`2.

`Server A1` contains `5 DATABASES`. But I moved only 2 databases from `A1` to `A2` during the migration of databases from server A1 to Server A2.

I want to drop the users, who are not required on server `A2`, because of remaining databases which were not migrated on it.

Please help with any scripts or dmvs to identify which users are not required on server `A2` and thereby dropping them.

If a user has access to multiple databases, how can we remove the login of that  user whose concerned database was not migrated from server `A1` to `A2`.

Thanks in advance, any valuable suggestions would be helpful for our POC.

Comment: check [SQL Server Security Auditing to Match Logins And Users](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2088/sql-server-security-auditing-to-match-logins-and-users/) and [this msdn blog -- especially in the comments by Raul Garcia](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2006/07/03/655587.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of migrating or transferring all the users from server A to server B, you should have identified the orphan users for the migrated databases.

Say from server 1 , as you said you moved database A and B:

1) Find orphan users on database A- Once you have found them , mapped the orphan users with help of script you used earlier to find the logins on server A

2) Find orphan users on database B- Once you have found them , mapped the orphan users with help of script you used earlier to find the logins on server A.

For more on how to find orphan and map them [read this article on Orphan users](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175475.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

The query below will show you all of the users who have permissions on the server but do not have explicit permissions on the databases.

```
    SELECT P.name
     , D1.name AS DatabaseName_1
     , D2.name AS DatabaseName_2
    FROM sys.server_principals P
     LEFT OUTER JOIN <Database1>.sys.database_principals D1 ON D1.[SID] = P.[SID]
     LEFT OUTER JOIN <Database2>.sys.database_principals D2 ON D2.[SID] = P.[SID]
    WHERE D1.name IS NULL AND D2.name IS NULL
```

- Change "Database1" and "Database2" to be the relevant database names.